# Merging video in a specific order using ffmpeg

Tags: ffmpeg, terminal, concatenation

I use the following to merge video in numeric order.

`for f in *; do mv "$f" "${f: -17}"; done &&. find *.ts|. sed 's:\:\ :g'| sed 's/^/file /' > fraglist.txt && ffmpeg -f concat -safe 0 -i fraglist.txt -c copy  output.ts; rm fraglist.txt`

This works great for files named like the following... 
000001

000002

000003

000004

000005

000006

000007

000008

000009

000010

But If I need something like the following merged the order is based on how many digits there are in the file name...

1708.ts 
 9803.ts 
 13798.ts 
 17815.ts  
 21804.ts 
 25819.ts 
29832.ts

What command could I use to get the second group of files merged in that order?  Thank you for your help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simplify your whole process by using `printf` alone to make the txt file contents, and use `sort` to provide natural/version sorting:

```
printf "file '%s'\n" *.ts | sort -V > fraglist.txt
ffmpeg -f concat -i fraglist.txt -c copy output.ts
```

Result:

```
file '1708.ts'
file '9803.ts'
file '13798.ts'
file '17815.ts'
file '21804.ts'
file '25819.ts'
file '29832.ts'
```

- No need to `rm fraglist.txt` as the `sort` redirect (`>`) will overwrite `fraglist.txt`.
- Note that I removed `-safe 0` (an option specific to the [concat demuxer](https://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg-formats.html#concat)) from the `ffmpeg` command because you don't need it in this exact example. But if you get the `Unsafe file name` error (such as due to special characters including spaces) then you will need to add it.